# custom buttons on uiwebview(iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I want to add custom button on webView. they should also should be there when i try anything in url.

how is it possible??

basically i want to put buttons on  uiwebView and they are custom buttons

//edited code...

I am doing this...here link is appearing but method is not getting called...and there wasnot any error in your code ..:)

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *HTMLData = @"<html<a href=\"button://dosomething\" class=\"buttonStyle\">Click me!</a>--></style><br><br>";

[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];
```

and then

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    // only do something if a link has been clicked...
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {     

        // check if the url requests starts with our custom protocol:
        if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"button://"]) {
            // Do custom code
            return NO;
        } 
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You can add html buttons to your webview's content.

Comment: yes yes...I want to do that but how can i do that?

Comment: Do you have the full control over the content of the html?

Comment: yes I have the full control on that :)

Comment: nick...there is not any problem in your code but method is not getting called :(

Comment: I am not getting this method called nick

Comment: did you set `myWebView.delegate = self`? And does your class conform to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol?

Comment: yes..I have declared `@interface myWebViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>`and `myWebView.delegate = self`

Comment: Nick ...its done...mistake from my side it was...`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` i was passing parameters of myweb here...sorry..and ya u r a gem man..thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll just have to use links and style them.

Something like:

```
<a href="#" class="buttonStyle">Click me!</a>
```

Have a look at http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/, very easy to create your own button and let it generate the css code for you. You'll actualy have to click on the button create itself to generate the code.

**Execute custom code by clicking on a link(button) in html**

First of all you've got to conform to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol, and set the delegate accordingly.

Then implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

You button links should look like this:

```
<a href="button://dosomething" class="buttonStyle">Click me!</a>
```

We are using a custom protocol we make up: `button://`.

Now implement shouldStartLoadWithRequest like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    // only do something if a link has been clicked...
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {     

            // check if the url requests starts with our custom protocol:
        if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"button://"]) {
            // Do custom code
            return NO;
        } 
    }

    return YES;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: okay...i am trying it..will let you know..thanks :) and up :)

Comment: okay..nick...here is the real thing...i have some html code and I want some button to be there on my iphone screen and whenever I touch that button,some specific method should get called..how to use this button there??

Comment: I knew that this question would come :) I'll explain in a second.

Comment: bacause here only link is coming..:) with click me link and should I have to implement the CSS for that button in my .m file??

Comment: Just a question: You need to call an objective-c method when clicked on the button, right? You've got to implement the button or better style your button in your html and the css files(or inline if you don't have one linked).

Comment: Here you go, added some code and the mechanics behind it. However I've got to throw out some things from working code, so this may have errors, but you'll get the picture.

Comment: Is it normal to see a delay (around 0.5 sec) when capturing the click event in your UIWebViewDelegate?