# ios - how to create a screen with a lot of text and buttons and not use UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I can not use `UIWebView` because I want the text to be accessible even if the user does not have Internet access on their phone.  Also, I will need to have buttons to other screens on the app and I think that is not possible with `UIWebView` (right?)

Is there a way for me to edit the xml of the screen directly inside Xcode? My requirement is to have about 10 sections with header labels and buttons before each, so if I have to adjust it on the storyboard screen, it will be a bit nightmarish.

What is a reasonable approach for me here? I think only to edit the xml by hand and hardcode it with styles and text, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you consider using a `UIWebView` it doesn't mean you are restricting your application functionality to internet access.

You can just as well have HTML documents in the application bundle that you display in a webview. This is basically what PhoneGap is doing.

If you don't want to use webviews then nothing is stopping you from using `UIViews`, `UILabels`, `UIImageViews` etc and compose your app how you want.

Comment: take a look at my answer to Dima.  I have about 10 such pages I need to make, and each page has many elements.  What I am looking for is a least-pain way to do this.  Also, if I do use UIWebView, and display a web page, will I need to make that page "responsive" ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by responsive but there is a delegate method for the webview which will let you intercept hyperlinks loading. If you needed to you could intercept a button being tapped, and know which one it was. All your ressources (images etc) could all be inside your app, and you wouldn't need an internet connection. I prefer to use native at all times, if you've really got that many things on your view, maybe you can split it into smaller sections and have a uiview for each section, splitting it up means less "huge chunk of hard coded values", maybe end up with a tiled view.

Comment: by responsive I meant "responsive design" where the html page adjusts to narrower screens if seen by tablets or phones.

Comment: If you decide to do HTML documents inside webviews, your CSS is responsible for the different screen sizes, please see here for how to target iPhone or iPad screens with CSS: http://perishablepress.com/target-iphone-and-ipad-with-css3-media-queries/

Comment: ah I understand, then the answer to my question is yes, my HTML pretty much should be responsive :)

Comment: I thought HTML was the only option for webviews...is there something else? I don't really feel like doing it in html if there was another way that might be simpler.

Comment: I would much prefer "cutting" my UI into sections, maybe a "header", "sub header", "important info", "more section", "footer", then if you really wanted to go native, you would subclass UIView to get a bunch of custom views, pass in the info and lay them out, you would need a method to calculate how high your view is. Back in your main view controller you prepare these "sections" or "tiles" and lay them out, knowing for each how high they are thanks to that method I mentioned. That way your view controller has only a handful of views and not hundreds of them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15298/discussion-between-geekedout-and-daniel)

Answer (score 2):

several things here:

1. webviews only need an internet connection if you are downloading the content for the view (which doesnt seem like what you want anyway, aren't you just building it locally?)
2. you can make the buttons in a webview do whatever you want. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920102/custom-buttons-on-uiwebviewiphone) answer.
3. What is so complex about this UI that you can't just build it the regular way in code or IB?

Comment: answering your question from #3, the ui is long and there are 30+ elements: 10 buttons, 10+ texts, and 10+ headings....and there are a number of such screens that need to be made.  So it doesn't scale to make it by hand from the storyboard.  If it was a matter of just editing the page directly, it would be more bearable.

Comment: Is it possible the pages are similar enough that you can condense them into a single reusable UIViewController subclass that will configure itself based on which page it's supposed to display? Otherwise, you can write some utility function to programmatically create your subviews and call it from each view. I am not sure how plausible it is to mess with the xml directly underneath Xcode's GUI, so I can't comment on that. In general, it does not seem like the right way to do things.

Comment: I think it would not be possible to do this programatically.  The text and buttons just vary too much. I just don't understand how Apple wants people to create text-heavy screens...there doesn't seem to be a reasonable way. :(